# Rotate a background element slightly

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I have created a lay-out where the background element is slightly rotated to the upper-left.

But however I saw something you can do it with SVG but never actually worked with it before.

Right now I use the following technique:

```
.background {
  width:100%;
  margin-left: -160px;
  margin-right: -160px;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

and that rotate the elements the opposite direction that they are just horizontal aligned.

But it doesn't really fit my screen when I zoom out or I need to have a lot of negative margins but I don't think that is a nice way of solving this.

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/denniswegereef/pen/jqLPJd) how things are right now.

Below is how it should look:

[image]

The above image is just one tile for sample. [Here is how it would actually look in the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqWBn.jpg) The black stripes are full width of your screen is the idea.

No `hover` effects are needed on the shape it just needs to be static.

Comment: please share something wht u want

Comment: Oh sorry, I edit it with an imgur of the design I created on photoshop

Comment: Sorry, accidentally deleted my previous comment. Are you specifically looking for a SVG answer (or) is something like [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/WwEQbP) acceptable?

Comment: That is exactly how I want it, I prefer this solution for now and can always look back when I have some more time for a SVG replacement. Thanks alot !

Comment: But this one is a little buggy in chrome compared to the first one

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/YEnO6bi.png and version Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit)

Comment: I'm also trying to find a solution for it, no idea where it is coming from

Comment: That would be great, I really like your :after solution already

Comment: By the way, do you need to have any `:hover` effects on that shape?

Comment: Not on the shape it just needs to be static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very simple to create this with SVG. Just use a `path` element (or a `polygon` element), create  a shape similar to the required one and then place it absolutely with respect to the parent container. To position it behind the text, give it a negative `z-index`.

The SVG `path` commands are pretty easy to understand and can be interpreted as follows:

- `M0,0` - This means "move" the imaginary pen to the point 0,0 on the canvas.
- `L100,10` - This means draw a "line" from the previous point to the point 100,10 on the canvas.
- `100,100` - Similar to the above one (a `L` is assumed to be in front).
- `0,90` - Similar to the above again.
- `z` - This means "close the path". That is, draw a line from the previous point to starting point.

You can read more about the SVG `path` commands in [this MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths). It is very helpful.

```css
.rotate-background {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.rotate-background svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
p {
  width: 500px;
  color: white;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate-background">
  <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
    <path d='M0,0 L100,10 100,100 0,90z' />
  </svg>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quae cum magnifice primo dici viderentur, considerata minus probabantur. Quae hic rei publicae vulnera inponebat, eadem ille sanabat. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Illa videamus,</p>
</div>
```

---

We can do this with CSS `transform: skewY()` and pseudo-element also like in the below snippet.

```css
.rotate-background {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.rotate-background:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: skewY(2deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  color:white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate-background">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quae cum magnifice primo dici viderentur, considerata minus probabantur. Quae hic rei publicae vulnera inponebat, eadem ille sanabat. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Illa videamus, </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, impressive looks in incredibly gonna use this. Is it actually also better to use SVG for things like this?

Comment: @Dennis: Generally SVG is recommended for complex shapes. This one is kind of simple to do with CSS and so either one is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using percentages or em's rather than a fixed pixel margin?

```
.rotate-background {
  height: 300px;
  width: 120%;
  margin-left: -10%;
  margin-right: -10%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  background-color:black;
}
```